# Why is my JQuery method not being called

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

Standard project structure.Using JSP, JQuery and Spring framework.

The issue is simple, the AJAX call is not functioning as expected. I'm hoping for the input value to be sent to the backed, and an alert 'success' to appear in browser to the end user.

However, this case is behaving as though the Jquery call is non existent.

JS Resources are located:

> WEB-INF/resources/js

JSP:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Lorem Ipsum</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/subscribe.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="jumbotron text-center">
          <form class="form-inline" action="/intuition/subscribe" method="post">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" size="50" placeholder="Email Address" required>
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Subscribe</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

subscribe.js

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
 /* attach a submit handler to the form */
     $("#form-inline").submit(function(event) {

       /* stop form from submitting normally */
       event.preventDefault();

       /* get the action attribute from the <form action=""> element */
       var $form = $( this ),
           url = $form.attr( 'action' );

       /* Send the data using post with element id name and name2*/
       var posting = $.post( url, { name: $('#email').val() } );

       /* Alerts the results */
       posting.done(function( data ) {
         alert('success');
       });
     });
});
```

Comment: The submit event listener is never attached... You are listening to the submit event of an element with id `#form-inline`, but your form has a class of `.form-inline`.

Comment: @JoshCrozier is correct or you need to add ID form-inline.

Comment: this update does not correct the behaviour. I have also added an id to the email input type.

Comment: to clarify - the undesired behavior is that on form submission, the server is responding with and the browser loads, a new page.

Comment: The submission event is not called as @Josh Crozier said, remove the `method="post"` from your form element you don't need that and maybe is one of the reasons that your request is not working and in your `var posting = $.post( url, { name: $('#email').val() } );` you try to grab the id `#email` from your input field but in your input there is not an id attribute at all.

Comment: actually, the method post is required as the js states -- the get the action attribute from the <form action=""> element  is used. In addition I have commented that I already updated the email id to no avail.

Comment: should it not be <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/subscribe.js" type="text/javascript"></script> ?
is the js file even loaded?

Comment: correct, good spot. On inspecting the network traffic,  there is a post being sent out,  and the js file is being loaded. However, the expected behaviour from the controller is not being produced. the application just sits idly, and the sys.out in the method is not being called.